# Significance of distribution of CDF of a continuous random variable is Uniform

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is there a physical significance to the fact that the distribution of a continuous random variable $Y=F_{X}(x)$ is $U[0,1]$? I don't need the mathematical proof, rather an intuitive explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: You probably mean $F_X(X)$ (not $F_X(x)$).

Comment: Essentially because with probability $1$, $F\left(F^{-1}(y)\right)=y$ for $y \in (0,1)$.  This does not happen with discrete random varaibles

Answer (score 0):

The significance is that we can generate random numbers of any distribution if we have the inverse of the cdf requested and if we have random number generator providing random numbers, $Y$, uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.

$$P(F^{-1}(Y)<x)=P(Y<F(x))=F(X).$$

So we simply plug the uniform random number in $F^{-1}(x)$ and the distribution of the result is of $F$.

(Note: the inverse always exists since the cdf if monotonously increasing.)